# Kendo UI does not work with jQuery-2.1.1

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datetimepicker

Currently i am working with jQuery-2.1.1, angularJs-1.3.12 and Kendo UI v2014.3.1316. i used component such as grid, drop down list and date time picker from Kendo UI. but none of these components are working except kendo grid and please find below configurations.

Please advise to fix this.

```
//HTML

<input type="text" name="DTEndDate"
kendo-date-picker
k-format="'MMMM yyyy'"
k-options="monthSelectorOptions">

//Js
<!--//Kendo-->
<script src="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>

//CSS   

<!-- KENDO CSS-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.metro.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.dataviz.metro.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/kendo/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice is to use a compatible version of jQuery, i.e. [2.0.x](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites). Your version is simply untested and thus not supported.